# Providing Schematics to a Contract Manufacturer?

Tags: manufacturing

A contract manufacturer mentioned the types of the files that they need in order to build and assemble boards. He indicated that they need the schematics along with gerbers, drill files, bom etc..

Is this common practice for CMs to ask for schematics ?

Is it common practice to bundle schematics with a fabrication+assembly package ?

Comment: Are they contracted to do any functional testing?

Comment: From the initial conversation - we didn't even get to that. But most likely no. But even if there was functional testing, wouldn't a test plan document be sufficient ?

Comment: In case you provide one... Anyway, you can ask them. I remember we have provided schematics to manufacturer at one of my previous jobs.. but these were in locked PDF format or even just hardcopies

Comment: @EugeneSh. No risk of someone within the organization, cloning in asian markets ? Which is my concern but my concern could be misplaced - so I am checking to see what others in this field doing.

Comment: We used a local manufacturer with NDA, so I guess the situation might be different.

Comment: You should definitely have them to sign NDA if you consider some of the materials they need your IP.

Answer (score 5):

> Is this common practice for CMs to ask for schematics ?

Yes, I've had a few ask about it. Do I send them, No. They don't need them. Usually the problem is over a repair, or a question about a section of the design. I ask them what designators they need to look at and if they really need it, I send them a subsection of the schematic.

> Is it common practice to bundle schematics with a fabrication+assembly
>   package ?

Don't send out your IP (intellectual property) to contract manufactures, it's not good business or engineering practice.

The contract manufacturer can get what they want through good communication without the risk of compromising IP.

If the contract manufacturer were redesigning a schematic, yes you would need to send them the schematic.

Comment: This has been my practice so its good to know your experience as well.

Comment: Also mine. They ask for it, but they don't argue if I don't provide it.

Comment: It’s trivial to reverse engineer a schematic from the rest of the package so to improve Testability for yields if using ICT, this is necessary

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 if a test document is provided which includes which test points to probe and what their expected values are - is a schematic necessary or if using ICT this is typical to provide full schematics ?

Comment: For some reason they decided to include a netlist in the ODB++ format. And I guess for testability a netlist would be enough?